# What happens when a city with Macchu Picchu loses the mountain Macchu Picchu is located on?

Tags: civilization-5

The below image is a screengrab from [episode 16 of the Yogscast Civilization V: Donut Island season.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6p-ClVmoVlA) As you can see, England (Pyrion Flax) has built Macchu Picchu in his city.

Now, suppose Poland (Lewis Brindley) uses a Great General on the hill tile to the west of Macchu Picchu, meaning England loses the mountain Macchu Pichu was built on. Macchu Picchu can only be built on top of a mountain. What happens to Macchu Picchu?

1. Does England lose Macchu Picchu?
2. Does England keep Macchu Picchu?
3. Does Macchu Picchu switch hands from England to Poland?

Related: Does the existence of other mountains in England's city domain make a difference?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wonder belongs to the city, not the mountain tile.  Whoever controls the city controls Macchu Picchu, regardless of where the game decides to display it.

This was also a [topic of discussion on CivFanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=518561), where they reached the same conclusion.  In fact, someone had a city where Macchu Picchu appeared in the theoretical outer limit of the city's boundaries, on a tile that the civ didn't (and never) owned, despite there being closer mountain tiles that were inside the city's radius already.

Comment: There was some speculation in the CF thread that losing access to *all* mountain tiles while building Macchu Picchu would likely cancel the build, since the requirements for building the wonder were no longer met.

Comment: So it doesn't switch sides, but what *does* happen if the city no longer controls any nearby mountains? Nothing? Does it stop giving benefits until they get a mountain back?

Comment: @MikeKellogg, if you lose all the mountains after it's built, but keep the city then you still get to keep it and the bonuses.  The game doesn't check to see if there are still mountains present after it's built.